# Smoothscroll not working when importing html from file

Tags: jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I have an issue importing html using jquery. Importing this text will break the smoothscroll plugin

When importing html with jquery:

```
$(document).ready
    (
        function() 
        {
            $("#about_div").load("test_scroll.html");
        }
    );
```

I load the following line of html:

```
<a href="#photography" class="smoothScroll"> Photography</a>
```

When looking to the source of the page i also see:

```
<a href="#photography" class="smoothScroll"> Photography</a>
```

In my menu I have the exact same code (but not imported):

```
<a href="#photography" class="smoothScroll"> Photography</a>
```

When I click the link in my menu smoothscroll works, but when I click the imported link I just pointed to page [www.peterstreef.nl/scrolltest/](http://peterstreef.nl/scrolltest)#photography which jumps to the section.

If I add smoothscroll links before or after this div the links work fine, so it has nothing to do with include order.

So my question is, how can I import HTML without breaking smoothscroll?
I've made a simple test page to reproduce the problem:
[www.peterstreef.nl/scrolltest/](http://peterstreef.nl/scrolltest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open your smoothscroll.js file, at the end you will see this:

```
// Initialize all .smoothScroll links
jQuery(function($){ $.localScroll({filter:'.smoothScroll'}); });
```

This means that, when loaded, the library only initializes existing links and does not take into account the rest of the links loaded afterwards with *.load()*.

The solution for this problem is to initialize the loaded a.smoothScroll again. For that you can change your JS code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#about_div").load("test_scroll.html", function() {
       $("#about_div").localScroll({filter:'.smoothScroll'});
    });
});
```

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing it had to be because I load on document.ready which is after loading smoothscroll.js. Had no idea how to fix it yet though, thanks a lot for the solution!